# Does an actual transaction happen on the blockchain when you buy btc/usdt?

Tags: transactions, security, storage

I was wondering if I buy or sell something on the exchange if coins are actually transfered somewhere of if the exchange just changes values of what belongs to me.

Answer (score 2):

No, when you buy Bitcoin from an exchange, it is not an on-chain transaction, the exchange simply updates your account balances in their database.

It only becomes an on-chain transaction when you either deposit or withdraw Bitcoin to or from a Bitcoin address, from your exchange account.